# setting a view name when used nested_route in Django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm new to django. I want to test my ViewSet(Django = 1.11) but I got this error message.

```
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'license' not found. 'license' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

I want to figure out what should I put in the reverse() as parameter.

urls.py

```
urlpatterns += util.get_nested_route_urls(
router=router, lookup='member', domain='license', view_set=MemberLicenseViewSet,
base_name='member_license')
```

test.py

```
class MemberLicenseViewSetTestCase(APITestCase):
     url = reverse("license")
     factory = APIRequestFactory()
     views = MemberLicenseViewSet.as_view
```